# How to retrieve random elements from a Python 3 generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, combinations

Someone suggested [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1227692/862423) for generating combinations: this will give me combinations, but, will not have the desired propoerties (for which post processing is needed) as mentioned in the **end** of my question.
Please understand, `len(myList) = 10e6` and desired combinations even larger.
I am working with graphs.

---

Lets say I have a **very large** list. I am generating **combinations** for this list using itertools. What I want to achieve is to select the elements at random, without materializing the generator (*it is too big even for 16 GB of RAM, I learnt that the hard way*).

Here, is what I have done so far:

```
import itertools
import random


myList = [('abc',1), ('bcd',2), ('cdef',3), ('adcv',4), ('zofd',5), ('qmkdf',6), ('qmk',7), ('oswd',8)]
# actual list is much larger than above in my case

myCombi_gen = itertools.combinations(myList, r=2)
# Above should generate: [(('abc',1), ('bcd',2)), (('abc',1), ('cdef',3)), .....]

N = 15
counter = 0

for elem in myCombi_gen:
    if random.random() > 0.5:       # selecting based on probability
        print(elem, end=' ')
        counter+=1
        # doing something useful here
        if counter == N:
            break
```

My problem is, the elements in the combinations that end up being selected are **concentrated at a locality**. I want them to be more uniformly spread out (may be some distribution?). Some heads up will be helpful.

---

**Notes**:

Even without the probabilistic selection I need only a fraction of the combinations. That simply picks up the first **N** elements if randomised selection is not used. Code updated accordingly.

For clarity, for my specific case, I can't do the following:

```
# Cannot do the following, memory (RAM) usage blows up

all_combi = list(itertools.combinations(myList, r=2))
random.shuffle(all_combi)
selected_combi = random.sample(all_combi, N)
```

---

A common approach suggested by many seems to be, why not sample `myList` and then generate combinations? No. I have updated the structure of myList for better understanding. It is sorted and has to remain so. `itertools.combinations` generates sorted combinations which suits my purpose, that is why I used it (I am open to any other combination generator). I want the sampling to be performed on the combinations, not on the original elements of `myList`.

```
# This approach is unacceptably slow (though I didn't time it):

# making random combinations of size 2
selected = set()
while True:
    left = random.choice(myList)
    right = random.choice(myList)

    if left[1] < right[1] and left[0] != right[0] and (left, right) not in selected and (right, left) not in selected:
        selected.add((left, right))
    if len(selected) == N:
        break
```

Comment: Just a clarification. You wish to get all possible pair wise combinations of the list right ?

Comment: updated the question @TanishqVyas

Comment: `myCombi_gen = itertools.combinations(myList)` doesn't seems right.  `itertools.combinations` needs to 2 arguments.

Comment: my bad, @AbhigyanJaiswal I was writing and not copying from my editor so missed the `r=2` argument. I wish to generate combinations of size 2, as shown in the example in comment.

Comment: A possible way can be to store the list entities in a file (probably a csv file) and then get the total number of lines in that csv file. Then randomly generate an integer in that range and select the entry on that line in the csv and similarly select a random entry at some other line. Then read the two lines for their data and use wherever you wish. Thus you may use a generator to do the same.

Comment: Just a clarification to be double sure. The main issue is that the data to be stored in myList is too huge (much larger than 16GB) thus you cannot store that in the list and use the above approach right ?

Comment: @TanishqVyas, the real issue is localization, please have a look at question update.

Comment: What about selecting from each list on probability in advance, pick elements and combine.

Comment: @anurag In order to get a proper distributed data you can do what's called a stratified sampling. Partition your myList into some sub lists and select these lists at random. Then select the element at random from each selected list. That way it wont be localized to a certain section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/). With 1M permutations, it takes less than 1 minute.

`random_combination`:

> Return a random *r* length subsequence of the elements in *iterable*.
> This equivalent to taking a random selection from
> `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`.

```
from more_itertools import random_combination, random_permutation
import string

s = string.ascii_letters
g = {tuple(random_permutation(s)) for i in range(1000000)}

result = set()

while len(result) != 15:
    if (c := random_combination(g, r=2)) not in result: result.add(c)
```

Comment: many answers were posted, some literally increased my  knowledge, but, the posters chose to remove the answers. I was under the impression that SO is for the community. Anyways, I find this answer the most simple and elegant. Thanks @Henry, and bigger thanks to the creators (https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/). I will accept this. (May be edit later to match my question.)

Answer (score 1):

This should help with solving the localization problem.

```
import random

N = 15
counter = 0


# List of data
myList = [['abc', 'bcd', 'cdef', 'adcv', 'zofd', 'qmkdf', 'qmk', 'oswd'],
          ['zbc', 'zcd', 'zdef', 'zdcv', 'zofd', 'zmkdf', 'zmk', 'zswd'],
          ['ahhc', 'gcd', 'fdef', 'fdcv', 'gofd', 'gmkdf', 'gmk', 'gswd']]

num_lists = 2

while counter < 15:

    # Randomly select n lists
    sampled_lists_index = random.sample(list(range(len(myList))), num_lists)

    for i in sampled_lists_index:
        # print(i)
        print(random.sample(myList[i], 1)[0], end=" ")

    # Taking care of the formatting
    print("\n")     

    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for the question:

```
from more_itertools import random_combinations as rc

N = 15

myList = [('abc',1), ('bcd',2), ('cdef',3), ('adcv',4), ('zofd',5), ('qmkdf',6), ('qmk',7), ('oswd',8)]

result = set()

while len(result) != N:
    c = rc(myList, r=2)
    if c not in result:
        result.add(c)
```

this will produce the following:

```
{(('qmkdf', 6), ('qmk', 7)), (('cdef', 3), ('zofd', 5)), (('adcv', 4), ('zofd', 5)), (('bcd', 2), ('cdef', 3)), (('bcd', 2), ('qmk', 7)), (('adcv', 4), ('qmk', 7)), (('bcd', 2), ('adcv', 4)), (('abc', 1), ('zofd', 5)), (('abc', 1), ('oswd', 8)), (('cdef', 3), ('oswd', 8)), (('adcv', 4), ('qmkdf', 6)), (('cdef', 3), ('qmkdf', 6)), (('bcd', 2), ('oswd', 8)), (('abc', 1), ('qmkdf', 6)), (('bcd', 2), ('qmkdf', 6))}
```

Please note that the combinations are random yet follow the sort order.